# audio is finished then play button icon show again

Tags: javascript, html

we make coding, when this audio is finished we need play button show again.
now after finish the audio show only pause button please solve this problem. and i also add dowload audio button to user download this audio.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            
            
            myAudio.onplaying = function() {
              isPlaying = true;
            };
            myAudio.onpause = function() {
              isPlaying = false;
            };
        });
        
        var isPlaying = false;
        var button  = document.getElementById("play-pause-btn");
        function togglePlay() {
            if (isPlaying) {
                myAudio.pause()
                button.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle-o");
               button.classList.add("fa-play-circle-o");
                
            } else {
                myAudio.play();
                button.classList.add("fa-pause-circle-o");
               button.classList.remove("fa-play-circle-o");
            }
          
        }
```

```css
.d-table {
  display:table !important;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display:table-cell !important;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100% !important;
}


.tar {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class=" d-table w-100">
<p class="d-table-cell">بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</p>
  <div class="d-table-cell tar w-10">
 <audio id="myAudio" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Vug3C2rR1Mnpi1idxRvxZ6X0szsMf-o-" preload="auto"></audio> 
   <a onClick="togglePlay()" id="audio-btn"><button> <i id="play-pause-btn" class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-2x"></i></button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use onended event.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
            var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            
            
            myAudio.onplaying = function() {
              isPlaying = true;
            };
            myAudio.onpause = function() {
              isPlaying = false;
            };
            myAudio.onended = function(){
             var button  = document.getElementById("play-pause-btn");
               button.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle-o");
               button.classList.add("fa-play-circle-o");
            }
        });
        
        var isPlaying = false;
        var button  = document.getElementById("play-pause-btn");
        function togglePlay() {
            if (isPlaying) {
                myAudio.pause()
                button.classList.remove("fa-pause-circle-o");
               button.classList.add("fa-play-circle-o");
                
            } else {
                myAudio.play();
                button.classList.add("fa-pause-circle-o");
               button.classList.remove("fa-play-circle-o");
            }
          
        }
```

```css
.d-table {
  display:table !important;
}

.d-table-cell {
  display:table-cell !important;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100% !important;
}


.tar {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class=" d-table w-100">
<p class="d-table-cell">بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ</p>
  <div class="d-table-cell tar w-10">
 <audio id="myAudio" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Vug3C2rR1Mnpi1idxRvxZ6X0szsMf-o-" preload="auto"></audio> 
   <a onClick="togglePlay()" id="audio-btn"><button> <i id="play-pause-btn" class="fa fa-play-circle-o fa-2x"></i></button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended

Comment: working on this site,   this Site for  Tehreek Islah Muashara (Muhammad Ajmal Raza qadrI)  

http://islahemuashra.com/?page_id=5

Comment: Anees brother, one more help from you, i want add audio in every ayat. but this script problem in multi audio

Comment: can you please explain it a little bit more... I can't understand you.

Comment: surah fateha mai 7 ayat hai, mai chahta hu har ayat k samnay us ki audio play krnay ka button ho.is script sy ek hi audio play hoti hai., can you help me , to play seperate audio on every ayat

Comment: are you checked brother

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187705/discussion-between-scatter-instruments-and-anees-ijaz).

Comment: Thank you, now i am solved those problem, in future i need any help in this project will be contact you soon

Comment: yeah sure... sorry for not replying you .. I was busy in another project...